# Applicable iPhone graphics library

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I've tried reading up on Core Animation, Quartz, OpenGL, and cocos2d. While I think I have a feeling what they're all meant for, I still can't decide what's appropriate for the project I'm undertaking. The requirements are straight forward, I need to be able to import a custom font and draw it. I need to draw lines and arcs.

I tried using OpenGL ES for this, but it was very hard to work in custom fonts. Between Quartz and Core Animation, I'm not sure what's applicable. The application will always be in 2D. Performance is important. I have a feeling Quartz might not be appropriate since you can use a finger swipe to move the screen to a different part of the content and it seems that redrawing that much content with Quartz is heavy on the GPU. Not sure though, this is all from reading.

The outlier is cocos, since it seems to fit into a couple different buckets. It seems closer to OpenGL, but without the insanity when it comes to loading in custom fonts. There didn't seem to be enough info to get a feel for whether it would fit for this project though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pretty extensive experience with both Corona and Cocos2d. Corona is easy to use and great for a beginning programmer. There's a fairly large class of apps that you can write in Corona, but if you're looking for high performance, your best bet is Cocos2d. There's practically no 2D app you can think of that can't be written in Cocos2d. I recommend [Steffan Itterheim](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/)'s book if you're interested in learning it.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! So there should be no issue with the custom font stuff in cocos, right? I think that's my major concern after playing with OpenGL. Performance-wise cocos looks amazing. And then the only other follow up question is why you use cocos over Quartz or Core Animation.

Comment: No font issues that I ever encountered. You can do fonts two ways: (1) using actual truetype fonts, or (2) using bitmap fonts created by BMFont or Hiero. The latter is faster. I chose Cocos2d simply because I didn't know quartz or core animation at the time, and Cocos2d looked like a good library. I've never regretted that decision. :)

Comment: Thanks! Should be an interesting adventure.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need Ansca Mobile's Corona and x-pressive.com's Text Candy library:

[Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com)

[Text Candy](http://www.x-pressive.com/TextCandy_Corona/)

Comment: There are SO many choices! Thanks for the links. I'll have to look into them.

Comment: Corona + Text Candy provides a powerful 2D text platform for the iPhone.  Text Candy allows you to import custom bmp fonts or true type fonts and add deformations or animations.  Lua is a very easy language to learn and you can build pretty sophisticated apps in a very short time.  If you need blazing performance, then cocos2d or plain old obj-c is the way to go, but I've found Corona to be most adequate for just about anything.